# Eliminate duplicate values and replace them with null values oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table like

```
source  dest1  dest2
--------------------
su1     du1    st1
su1     du1    st2
su1     du1    st3
su2     du1    st1
su2     du2    st4
su2     du2    st1
```

But my desired table is

```
source  dest1  dest2
--------------------
su1     du1    st1
su1     du1    st2
su1     du1    st3
su2    (null) (null)
su2     du2    st4
su2     du2   (null)
```

Rule here is  Replacing dest2 by null if it appears once and  Replacing dest1, dest2 by null if dest1 appears once...

Comment: The rules you are using are not clear.

Comment: Can you explain the `null` on the last row?

Comment: Why is `dest2` of the 6th row `null` but it is not `null` for the 2nd or 3rd rows?

Comment: For a source su1--> dest1 du1 is alreay present so i need to replace that valueof dest1 of Su2 with null 
for dest1 du2 value of dest2 st1 is already present replace the value of dest2 with null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be null'ing out `dest2` after it appears once, and the pair when both appear.  Assuming that `source` provides the ordering, you can do:

```
select source,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by dest1, dest2 order by source) = 1
             then dest1
        end) as dest1,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by dest2 order by source) = 1
             then dest2
        end) as dest2
from t;
```